# Internal Namespace for .Net?

Tags: .net

Here is a simplified example:

```
namespace MyNS.Proj.InternalNS {
   internal class InternalClass1 {...}
}
```

I would like to make InternalNS as the part in MyNS.Proj invisible to outside since all the classes with the namespace are internal or private. Not sure if this is possible?

Comment: Since there is no need to expose any class or struc members in the InternalNS, I should not introduce it at all.

Answer (score 4):

[Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/namespaces) do not have access modifiers. The namespace will always be visible to external code even if its contents are not.

Answer (score 2):

The [`namespace` declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/using-namespaces#fully-qualified-names) had no accessibility modifiers. It will always be seen by external classes, even if all members are hidden.