# In C#, does wanting a namespace to be internal make any sense?

Tags: c#, oop, namespaces

I'm writing a class library and came across the need to make a namespace internal. I'm doing that because there's some auto-generated code coming from XSD, in order to have no collisions.

However, does wanting a namespace to be internal make any sense at all? I know it's not possible. I read this ( [Internal Namespace for .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135484/internal-namespace-for-net) ), amongst others.

What I'm asking is, if you think you want/need an internal namespace, what can be improved in your architecture/design? What should I move around in order to get rid of the false need to have an internal namespace?

Comment: Why do you want it to be internal versus simply YAN...yet another namespace...?

Comment: how would your hypothetical internal namespace work? Would it just be syntactic sugar for "all the classes in this namespace are internal"? Or would it mean "you can't declare classes with this namespace in any other assembly that references this one"?

Comment: How would this be different from just making all the types in that namespace internal? You can do that today, without needing to introduce some weird new syntax.

Comment: @paolo. I would pick a "syntactic sugar for 'all the classes in this namespace are internal'".

Comment: @Joe. That makes sense. The thing is the code I'm talking about is Auto Generated. Then every time I update it, I would have to change all classes to internal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, namespaces themselves have no particular accessibility. It's only the *members* of a namespace (types, basically) which have accessibilty. Simply make all the types in the namespace internal instead.

Comment: That's what I'm doing now. The thing is the code I'm talking about is Auto Generated. Then every time I update it, I would have to change all classes to internal. I guess that's just the way it is... I was thinking I could have another option

Comment: @Adrian: Ah, I see what you mean now. I would consider writing a rewriting tool which just that for you. It's a shame xsd.exe doesn't give you an option of generating internal types :(

Comment: You bet. I'm accepting your answer because of the "build your own tool" hint. BTW, I'm using Xsd2Code, which I found to be a neat tool. http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Adrian: Ah, well if you're already using a different tool, and an open source one at that, you can check whether that supports it - and implement it if not :)

Comment: Good call, I might as well just do that!

Answer (score 1):

Use `/namespace:<namespace>` attribute, when you generate classes from XSD, using `xsd.exe` tool.

[XML Schema Definition Tool (Xsd.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

`/n[amespace]:namespace` - Specifies the runtime namespace for the generated types.

If you have a typed DataSet, that was generated based on XSD, you can change `Customer Tool Namepsace` in DataSet properties.

Also, if your code is not bound to auto-generated DataSet and design tool, you can just change namespace manually, of course if you don't have to regenerate classes often.

If you need to generate classes often, make a bat (cmd) file that would run xsd.exe with the namespaces and class names that you want.

Also, if serialize/deserialize XML using XmlSerializer, you can't make classes internal.